# How to use a custom view correctly?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I have been trying to make a simple drawing program. Recently, I have figured out to draw shapes in a custom view for this purpose. My problem is that I have to draw everything at a single point in time. I don't know if that actually makes sense, but it seems to me that it calls the `drawRect` method only once, at that "once" is on startup.

Here is my code so far:

Header file.

```
NSBezierPath *thePath;
NSColor *theColor;
NSTimer *updateTimer;
NSPoint *mousePoint;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

@interface test : NSView {
    IBOutlet NSView *myView;

}

@property (readwrite) NSPoint mousePoint;

@end
```

Then, implementation in the .m file.

```
@implementation test

@synthesize mousePoint;

- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent*)someEvent {         
    CGEventRef ourEvent = CGEventCreate(NULL);
    mousePoint = CGEventGetLocation(ourEvent);
    NSLog(@"Location: x= %f, y = %f", (float)mousePoint.x, (float)mousePoint.y);
    thePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:NSMakeRect(mousePoint.x, mousePoint.y, 10, 10)];
    theColor = [NSColor blackColor];  

} 

- (void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)someEvent {
    mousePoint = [someEvent locationInWindow];
    NSLog(@"Location: x= %f, y = %f", (float)mousePoint.x, (float)mousePoint.y);
    x = mousePoint.x;
    y = mousePoint.y;
    [myView setNeedsDisplay:YES];

}

- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)rect; {
    NSLog(@"oisudfghio");
    thePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:NSMakeRect(x, y, 10, 10)];
    theColor = [NSColor blackColor];
    [theColor set];
    [thePath fill];

}
```

@end

On startup, it draws a rectangle in the bottom left corner, like it should. The problem is, the `drawRect` method is only called on startup. It just won't fire no matter what I do.

EDIT: I have just updated the code. I hope it helps.

SECOND EDIT: I have *really* simplified the code. I hope this helps a bit more.

Comment: I think you mean to call [self setNeedsDisplay:YES] not [myView setNeedsDisplay:YES]. test is the NSView subclass with the custom drawRect: method, so that's the view who's drawing you should invalidate.

Comment: @JonHess Thanks a lot! That solved my that problem! My image editor is now fully functional!

Answer (score 6):

**Short Answer:**
When your view's state is changed such that it would draw differently, you need to invoke -[NSView setNeedsDisplay:]. That will cause your view's drawRect: method to be called in the near future. You should never call drawRect: yourself. That's a callback that's invoked on your behalf.

When events occur in your application that cause you to want to change your drawing, capture state about what happened into instance variables, invoke setNeedsDisplay: and then later when drawRect: is called do the new drawing.

**Long Answer:**
In Cocoa, window drawing is done with an pull/invalidation model. That means the window has an idea of whether or not it needs to draw, and when it thinks it needs to draw it draws once per event loop.

If you're not familiar with event loops you can read about them on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)

At the top level of the application you can imagine that Cocoa is doing this:

```
while (1) {
   NSArray *events = [self waitForEvents];
   [self doEvents:events];
}
```

Where events are things like the mouse moving, the keyboard being pressed, and timers going off.

NSView has a method -[NSView setNeedsDisplay:]. It takes a boolean parameter. When that method is invoked the window invalidates the drawing region for that view, and schedules an event for the future to do redrawing - but only if there isn't a preexisting redrawing event scheduled.

When the runloop spins next time, the views that were marked with setNeedsDisplay: are re-drawn. This means you can call setNeedsDisplay: several times in a row and drawing will be batched to one call of drawRect: in the future. This is important for performance reasons and means you can do things like change the frame of a view several times in one method but it will only be drawn once at the final location.

Comment: This is a great answer Jon, I'd love it if you'd comment on what is the proper way to draw... is it all in the drawrect method or can if be done in the same method that messages the setNeedsDisplay

Comment: Hey cromestant, to draw, you need to use classes like NSBezierPath, NSString, and NSColor from within your drawRect: override. When ever you draw in Cocoa, there's an implicit destination that the system sets up for you using NSGraphicsContext. When your drawRect method is invoked the system has configured +[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] to point at the bitmap data that backs the view your window is on. At other times, a graphics context could be setup for the printer, or a off screen image. If you were to draw from outside drawRect:, the graphics context wouldn't be setup properly.

Comment: So basically, the only place where drawing code should go is within the drawRect override? Doesn't this make for a horribly cluttered drawRect method? For instance,  Say I'm developing an app that has a custom view, there is a button, when I press it an NSopen panel pops up, you select an image, and that image is loaded into the view. Then there is another button, with another NSOpen panel, that path is kept in memory, and lastly a third button that merges the 2 images, and displays the result in the custom view. the drawrect method should have 3 execution paths

Comment: One with nothing to paint, the second with the first image loaded, and the third with the composition? isn't this horribly cluttered? If you extrapolate this to a game, this would make things horribly complicated... If I'm not seeing this right could you point me to an example of how to properly do this?

Comment: You're free to make new methods to call from within drawRect:, but all of your drawing code should happen from within the context of one drawRect: callback, it doesn't have to literally be in the same method body.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your example has a couple of problems. The first is that all drawing code must be in the `drawRect:` method or a method called from `drawRect:`, so the drawing code you've placed in your other methods will have no effect at runtime. The second problem is that your code should never directly call `drawRect:`; instead, the framework will call it automatically (if necessary) once per event cycle.

Instead of hardcoding all the values, consider using instance variables for things you want to be able to change at runtime, for example, the drawing color and rectangle. Then in your `mouseDragged:` method, send the view (`myView` in your example) a `setNeedsDisplay:` message. If you pass `YES` as the argument, the `drawRect:` method will be called for you by the framework.

Comment: In theory, this should work. Unfortunately, it keeps telling me that it "might not respond to `setNeedsDisplay`. What now?

Comment: That's a `UIView` method. Here's what you need: `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];`

Comment: Its the same thing as what I have and it won't respond.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `[myView setNeedsDisplay:YES];` -- you have to send the message to the view instance that's doing the custom drawing. `self` here would have been the window, which is not a view and therefore is incapable of drawing, hence the warning message.

Comment: Ok. I have just updated the code again, and the `drawRect` method still won't even fire. Any other ideas?

Comment: Wow, you radically changed the code. In the previous version, the event methods were in a subclass of NSWindow.

Comment: I know. I almost cannot believe that I had that idea. The reason I had make two objects was so the `mouseDown` events would work. I was very lucky that it still worked with `NSView`.

Comment: It's not luck. `NSView` is a subclass of `NSResponder`, which is where the event methods are declared, and it's really common for subclasses of `NSView` to override them.

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind, I would like to talk you some more in the chat area sometime later this week (to solve some other problems I am having). I'm free anytime from 12:30-4:30 mountain time, if you would like to help some more

Comment: Hm, I don't really use SO chat.